# Adding sources.jar of an aar library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, javadoc

I have an .aar library with all the required stuff for developing but the documentation, so I've created an other .jar file which includes the documented source.

Now the problem: How can I tell Android Studio that the generated sources.jar file includes the documentation of the .aar library?

Comment: Could you add your build.gradle? Thanks

Comment: just the helloworld project gradle, nothing special

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export AAR library with its documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181814/how-to-export-aar-library-with-its-documentation)